# How to cummulative sum of array inside map function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequence, reduce

I am totally confused that how to implement cummulative  array.I think the best way to do this in reduce method.But i am little confused with that
Currently my output will look like this..
thanks in advance

output

```
    Jobs Inserted ====================>
    JobId:j8 Time to finish this Job :32
    JobId:j7 Time to finish this Job :22
    JobId:j2 Time to finish this Job :9
    JobId:j5 Time to finish this Job :8
    JobId:j4 Time to finish this Job :7
    JobId:j6 Time to finish this Job :5
    JobId:j1 Time to finish this Job :4
    JobId:j3 Time to finish this Job :1
    Machines Available :4
    Output =====================================>
//I want the result should be cummulative array
    MachineId:M1 Jobs done By this Machine:(j5 = 8),(j4 = 7),(j3 = 1) Time consumed to finish all jobs:16
    MachineId:M2 Jobs done By this Machine:(j2 = 9),(j6 = 5),(j1 = 4) Time consumed to finish all jobs:18
    MachineId:M3 Jobs done By this Machine:(j7 = 22) Time consumed to finish all jobs:22
    MachineId:M4 Jobs done By this Machine:(j8 = 32) Time consumed to finish all jobs:32
```

> Ex:-j5=8,j4=7+8=15,j3=16

like this

```
 MachineId:M1 Jobs done By this Machine:(j5 = 8),(j4 = 15),(j3 = 16) Time consumed to finish all jobs:16
        MachineId:M2 Jobs done By this Machine:(j2 = 9),(j6 = 14),(j1 = 18) Time consumed to finish all jobs:18
        MachineId:M3 Jobs done By this Machine:(j7 = 22) Time consumed to finish all jobs:22
        MachineId:M4 Jobs done By this Machine:(j8 = 32) Time consumed to finish all jobs:32
```

How to implement this...
this is my source code

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var njobs = [{
    jobname: "j1",
    time: 4
}, {
    jobname: "j2",
    time: 9
}, {
    jobname: "j3",
    time: 1
}, {
    jobname: "j4",
    time: 7
}, {
    jobname: "j5",
    time: 8
}, {
    jobname: "j6",
    time: 5
}, {
    jobname: "j7",
    time: 22
},
    {
        jobname: "j8",
        time: 32
    }

];

//sort this data with time
var sorted = njobs.sort((a, b) => b.time - a.time);

console.log('Jobs Inserted ====================>')

sorted.map(function (data) {
    console.log('JobId:'+data.jobname+' Time to finish this Job :'+data.time)
});

//List all the machines
var machines = [
    {
        id:1,
        value:0,
        jobs:[],
        name:'M1'
    },
    {
        id:2,
        value:0,
        jobs:[],
        name:'M2'
    },
    {
        id:3,
        value:0,
        jobs:[],
        name:'M3'
    },
    {
        id:3,
        value:0,
        jobs:[],
        name:'M4'
    }
];
console.log('Machines Available :'+ machines.length);
//Loop it and assign it
sorted.forEach(job => {
    var minMachine = machines
        .slice(1)
        .reduce((res, cur) =>
            res.value < cur.value ? res : cur, machines[0]);

    minMachine.jobs.push(job);
    minMachine.value += job.time;
});


//Prints the value

console.log('Output =====================================>');



machines.map(function (data) {
    console.log('MachineId:'+data.name+' Jobs done By this Machine:'+data.jobs.map(data => '('+data.jobname+' = '+data.time+')')+' Time consumed to finish all jobs:'+data.value)
});



var high = Math.max.apply(Math,machines.map(function (o) {
    return o.value;
}));
console.log('______________________________________________')
console.log('Highest Time consuming Machine =========>');
var result = _.findWhere(machines,{value:high});
console.log(result.name+' is the highest running Machine  '+result.value);
```

Comment: use `.reduce()` after your `.map()` function to sum all elements in an array: `machines.map(function (){...}).reduce(function (total, curr) { return total + curr; });` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: could pls add that as answer

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: No actually it is not working so pls provide the full example with my code @mhodges

Comment: @wrarar Yeah, from looking at your code, I didn't think it would, however, it answers your original question which was "how to sum all elements in an array". I will leave the comment and remove my answer because it does not solve your issue

Comment: any other way to solve this issue @mhodges

Comment: I'm working on trying to figure out exactly what you are asking for, to be honest.

Comment: just see the both output i've provided

Comment: Okay, I see. Let me work on it

Comment: I've also upated that question with one example @mhodges.Hope it understand

Comment: Got it figured out. Posting an answer shortly

Comment: Awesome bro I'm waiting... @mhodges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found your issue. In this case, you will need to build the string piece by piece, appending each job number and the current running total of time as you go. You can do this with the `.reduce()` function as mentioned before, or you can create a variable that keeps the total, and use a basic `forEach()`. The `reduce()` will be much cleaner, but the `forEach()` may be easier to understand if you were to refactor the code in the future - honestly it's your choice. Here's how I did it using `reduce()`:

Let me know if you have any questions!

```
machines.map(function (data) {
  var str = "MachineId:" + data.name + " Jobs done by this Machine:"
  data.jobs.reduce(function (total, curr){
    var newTotal = total + curr.time;
    str += "("+curr.jobname+" = "+newTotal+")";
    return newTotal;
  }, 0);
  str += ' Time consumed to finish all jobs:'+data.value;
  console.log(str);
});
```

#### Fully Working DEMO

```js
var njobs = [{
  jobname: "j1",
  time: 4
}, {
  jobname: "j2",
  time: 9
}, {
  jobname: "j3",
  time: 1
}, {
  jobname: "j4",
  time: 7
}, {
  jobname: "j5",
  time: 8
}, {
  jobname: "j6",
  time: 5
}, {
  jobname: "j7",
  time: 22
}, {
  jobname: "j8",
  time: 32
}];

//sort this data with time
var sorted = njobs.sort((a, b) => b.time - a.time);

console.log('Jobs Inserted ====================>')

sorted.map(function(data) {
  console.log('JobId:' + data.jobname + ' Time to finish this Job :' + data.time)
});

//List all the machines
var machines = [{
  id: 1,
  value: 0,
  jobs: [],
  name: 'M1'
}, {
  id: 2,
  value: 0,
  jobs: [],
  name: 'M2'
}, {
  id: 3,
  value: 0,
  jobs: [],
  name: 'M3'
}, {
  id: 3,
  value: 0,
  jobs: [],
  name: 'M4'
}];
console.log('Machines Available :' + machines.length);
//Loop it and assign it
sorted.forEach(job => {
  var minMachine = machines
    .slice(1)
    .reduce((res, cur) =>
      res.value < cur.value ? res : cur, machines[0]);

  minMachine.jobs.push(job);
  minMachine.value += job.time;
});


//Prints the value

console.log('Output =====================================>');



machines.map(function(data) {
  var str = "MachineId:" + data.name + " Jobs done by this Machine:"
  data.jobs.reduce(function(total, curr) {
    var newTotal = total + curr.time;
    str += "(" + curr.jobname + " = " + newTotal + ")";
    return newTotal;
  }, 0);
  str += ' Time consumed to finish all jobs:' + data.value;
  console.log(str);
});



var high = Math.max.apply(Math, machines.map(function(o) {
  return o.value;
}));
console.log('______________________________________________')
console.log('Highest Time consuming Machine =========>');
var result = _.findWhere(machines, {
  value: high
});
console.log(result.name + ' is the highest running Machine  ' + result.value);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
```